# Getting a 404 to this API

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have an API here: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/tree/AddingSpringJPA

I continue to get a 404 on either the `/greeting` or `/health`. The application starts up fine and deploys on 8080, I've also tried changing the listener port to something else but to no avail.

My Request:

`{
  "firstName": "Billy",
  "lastName": "Charter"
}`

Headers:
`Content-Type: application/json`
`Accept: application/json`

Response I get back:
`{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-22T16:20:30.874+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/greeting"
}`

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'My request..'? The api is a get method, you don't have body.

Comment: The `/greeting` is a post method noted by the `@RequestBody GreetingDTO greeting`, correct? I even specified` method = RequestMethod.POST` and still got a 404?

Comment: Added this is in also: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/def6a0120be3b211134ab1368d94e1812fe48565/complete/src/main/java/controller/GreetingController.java#L17

Comment: Do you happen to have set a context path property in your application.properties file?

Comment: No, here is my properties file: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/AddingSpringJPA/complete/src/main/resources/application.properties, is that something that might help? Sorry, I'm very new to Spring. :)

Comment: How are you making the request? With postman?

Comment: Yes, I also have a UI app, getting the same thing.

Comment: Ok, can you publish somewhere the output of the console log of the start of the boot app? Maybe a pastebin and link it here.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10zTnXUW-B5tmKwiq2zE_6bjBrw5CDbhWI14Cb0YQ3HY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this a spring boot app? It seems strange. The port is not written at the end. Neither are the mappings of the apis logged.I saw that server.port is commented, try enabling it.

Comment: Yep, cloned it from here myself: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Try to uncomment the server.port. And you run it as spring boot app, right?

Comment: Same logs, yep run it as a boot app.

Comment: I this API used to work, but I started adding in JPA and Hibernate stuff and it quit working. For Example my master branching will run fine: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API

Comment: Yes sir: noted here, https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/def6a0120be3b211134ab1368d94e1812fe48565/complete/src/main/java/application/Application.java#L9

Comment: Awesome, thank you for looking into this! I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBoot main class scans the folder "below" to find components.
Your `Application.java` is at the same level as your components, so none of your spring components are found.

Reorganize your project's sources as follow:

- com/projectname/Application.java
- com/projectname/controller/GreetingController.java
- com/projectname/service/GreetingService.java
- com/projectname/model/...
- com/projectname/dto/...
- com/projectname/dao/...

Also, while you're at it, remove the `@Component` on your DTO.

Comment: If that is the issue than I think the right place would be to have the application class  at the higher level, not in the application or controller folder.

Comment: not sure what you mean. Generally speaking the packages in this code sample are all wrong. But I'm using what I'm given to provide the answer. The Main class is in package `application`, so the controllers should be below, for example package `application.controllers`

Comment: I am saying that the Main class should be at the level of the other subfolders, not inside some folder.

Comment: Done, now it is saying it can not autowire the greetingService class? `Could not Autowire, no beans of  GreetingService type Found`?https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/42665a97112a6218269ef5d9834cdd72fb1322ba/complete/src/main/java/application/GreetingController.java#L13

Comment: @Billy Every spring component should be in a package below your "application.java". Please see my updated answer with an example of how you could be reorganizing your packages.

Comment: @NiVeR I'm pretty sure we say the same thing. The only issue was that his "first" package is "application".  So in my response that's where I put the main class, and then the spring components in sub-packages. I've updated my answer to suggest a better package structure

Comment: @alexbt You badass, that seems to have fixed it. Granted my Spring JPA does not work, but this big problem is fixed! Think my new error is more to do with my Hibernate mappings in my DAO object now. Thank you both!